# Converting multiple files from JPG to PNG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert multiple JPG files into PNG files. I'm able to do it for a single file but the loop doesn't seem to work for multiple files. Could you please help with that? I'm sharing my code below:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('./image.jpg')

img.save('new_image.png','png')

print('All done!')
```

Comment: *but the loop doesn't seem to work for multiple files*. What loop? Your code shown doesn't have a loop, so it's difficult to help with that problem.

Comment: You can convert all the JPEGs in the current directory to PNG without writing any Python, just using **ImageMagick** in Terminal like this `magick mogrify -format PNG *.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this -

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

counter = 0
for image in glob.glob("./*.jpg"):
    counter = counter + 1
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.save(str(counter)+'new_image.png','png')
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I use the code: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

#So the following code worked. Sorry for the formatting, I'm just beginning to learn!

from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

directory = r'C:\Users\Umar Iqbal\Desktop\newfolder' #this is where we will save our converted images

for image in glob.glob('./*.jpg'):
img = Image.open(image)

clean_name = os.path.splitext(image)[0] #if we don't use this, we get jpg in the file's name

img.save(f'{directory}{clean_name}.png', 'png') #this allows us to save the new images in the directory

Comment: You can click `edit` under your answer, select all the code with your mouse and click `{}` in the **Formatting Toolbar** beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code. Or just indent each line of code by 4 spaces.